# How to get a n-th element of a independent sequence?

Tags: arrays, sequence, element

Let's assume that our sequence is

3, 9, 7, 1 and then repeats itself 3, 9, 7, 1, and so on...

How can we check what value is going to be at e.g 605th element ( in that case it's gonna be 3)

PS: By "independent" I mean that we can't find mathematics formula.

Thanks in advance :P

## Edit adding ineffective code.

```
    public static int determine_value_at_position_of_an_array(List<int> sequence, int power)
    {
        int counter = 1; /// This index is going to value of power.
        int counter_2 = 0; /// This variable is responsible for jumping between [0..sequence.count-1]
        int current_value = 0;
        
        for (; counter<= power; counter++)
        {
            current_value = sequence[counter_2];
            if (counter_2==sequence.Count-1) /// if we're at last element, then go to 1st
            {
                counter_2 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                counter_2++;
            }
        }

        return current_value;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried to achieve this. Some code for example, doesn't have to be working. For more information on how to ask questions please check the [help-center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Deathstorm Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how much elements the repeating part of your sequence has(in your example 4) you can use the modulo operator(mostly % or mod) to receive the Nth element. here: 605 % 4 = 1 => first element => three.

**EDIT added some Code**

```
int valueAtN(List<Integer> sequence, int n) {
  return sequence.get(n % sequence.size());
}
```